# How to use Promise.prototype.finally() in async/await syntax?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Actually my main question was using `Promise.prototype.catch()` in `async/await` `ES8` syntax, Undoubtedly `Promise.prototype.then()` is existed in essence of `async/await` syntax.

I searched about using `Promise.prototype.catch()`  in `async/await` and found this:

```
async () => {
  try {
    const result1 = await firstAsynchronousFunction();
    const result2 = await secondAsynchronousFunction(result1);
    console.log(result2);
  } catch(err) {
    throw new Error(`Something failed`);
  }
}
```

And absolutely I knew about `Promise` chaining, like:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log(`Initial`);
  resolve();
})
.then(() => {
  console.log(`Task Number One`);
})
.catch(() => {
  console.log(`Task in Error`);
})
.finally(() => {
  console.log(`All Tasks is Done`);
})
```

So, my question is **how I can use `finally` in `async/await` syntax**?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

this should work:

```
async () => {
  try {
    const result1 = await firstAsynchronousFunction();
    const result2 = await secondAsynchronousFunction(result1);
    console.log(result2);
  } catch(err) {
    throw new Error(`Something failed`);
  } finally {
    console.log(`All Tasks are Done`);
  }
}
```