# How to return the fetched API status code and response to the next step in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using an API which returns correct HTTP code and one message related to that status code as result. I could find this solution in StackOverflow:

```
fetch(`${baseUrl}api/user/login`, {
    credentials: "include", // ¹ See note below
    headers: myHeaders
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status); // Will show you the status
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(// ... I need status code and error message here
```

but for this case, I've to use `response.json()` to get the error's message. So, I need a trick to return json data and status code to the next step then handle message alert.

I mean, there is not any message at first time and I've not access to the status code at next step to handle alert box's color.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way is to nest `then` calls.

```
return response.json().then(parsed_json => [response.status, parsed_json])
```

The clearer way is to rewrite your code to use `await` so that all the variables remain in scope and you don't need to return them explicitly.

```
const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}api/user/login`, {
    credentials: "include", // ¹ See note below
    headers: myHeaders
});
console.log(response.status); // Will show you the status
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
}
const parsed_json = await response.json();
console.log(parsed_json, response.status);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use the `finally` step to handle loading... can I keep for the response?

Comment: @MartinRützy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373337/how-to-use-promise-prototype-finally-in-async-await-syntax